# Create new ordinal variable from interval variable in Data frame preferably using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I want to create a new categorical variable in my dataframe based on an existing interval variable that simply aggregates the unique values into a smaller set of levels/values of the new variable.
I thought using a list comprehension below would be straight forward but I am getting the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-c03af1b75c0c>", line 3
    'set_2' elif x in (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My attempt is below:

```
df['new_variable'] = ['val_1' if x in (1995,1996,1997,1998,1999)
                   'val_2' elif x in (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004)
                   'val_3' elif x in (2005,2006,2007,2008,2009)
                   'val_4' elif x in (2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)
                    else 'val_5' for x in df['year']]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example (meaning some minimal dataframe that we can run to reproduce your error) so we can answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.select`

```
cond1 = df['year'].between(1995,1999)
cond2 = df['year'].between(2000,2004)
cond3 = df['year'].between(2005,2009)
cond4 = df['year'].between(2010,2014)

df['new_val'] = np.select((cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4),
                          ('val1','val2','val3','val4'),
                          default='val5')
```

Or with `pd.cut`:

```
df['new_val'] = pd.cut(df['year'], 
                       bins= list(np.arange(1994,2019,5)) + np.inf,
                       ['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5']
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This also may help you with another way:

```
def conditions(row):
    if row['year'] in [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]:
        return 'value_1'
    elif row['year'] in [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]:
        return 'value_2'
    elif row['year'] in [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]:
        return 'value_3'
    elif row['year'] in [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]:
        return 'value_4'
    else:
        return 'value_5'


df["new_variable"] = df.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   year new_variable
0  1994      value_5
1  1995      value_1
2  1996      value_1
3  2000      value_2
4  2010      value_4
5  2015      value_5
```